# If $25 = a^2$ then the value of a will be

Tags: square-numbers

My question is if $25 = a^2$ then the value of $a$ will be?

We always do it as if 
 $$
25 = a^2 \implies \sqrt{25}= \sqrt{a^2} \implies \pm 5 = a.
$$
However why don't we do it as 
$$
25 = a^2 \implies \sqrt{25}=\sqrt{a^2} \implies \pm 5 = \pm a
$$
Because $(+a )\times( +a) = a^2$ and also $(-a) \times( -a )= a^2$?

Comment: Both $5$ and $-5$ solve the given equation.  By definition, $\sqrt x$ is the positive square root of $x$.

Comment: The solutions of $25=a^2$ are indeed $a=5$ and $a=-5$. Note that for all real $x$, we have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, hence applying the square root function to both sides of $25=a^2$ we arrive at $5=|a|$, in other words $a=5$ or $a=-5$.

Comment: See related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250325/does-22-4-imply-2-pm-sqrt4/2233600#2233600).

Comment: Why did you add modulus to x

Comment: @Awesomeboy Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

To offer a different perspective to the comments, the plus-minus ($\pm$) before the $a$ is actually redundant. Observe that if you do all the plus-minus combinations you get
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
  (1) & 5 = a & (2) & -5 = a \\
  (3) & 5 = -a & (4) & -5 = -a \\
\end{array}
$$
But $(1)$ and $(4)$ are the same (check), and similarly $(2)$ and $(3)$ are the same (check). You get too many of the same answers with the second plus-minus.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write your equation as $$(5-a)(5+a)=0$$

Comment: I know that still in maths every method should lead to the same solution

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition of square root, the correct way to solve should be

$$a^2=25\iff \sqrt{a^2}=\sqrt{25}\iff |a|=5 $$

then $a=\pm 5$.

Answer (score 0):

$a=5$ and $a=-5$ are the solution of this equation.
If I take $y= 5$
And I take square  on both sides .then,we get $y^2=25$ 
After solving the quadratic equation. I get ,$y=\pm 5$.

But I doesn't take $y=-5$.

This type of solution is called a extraneous solution